# SVG compression with Angular 5 app hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure, gzip, azure-web-app-service

I'm having some trouble getting SVG's to gzip in our Angular 5 application hosted as an Azure Web App.

I tried to follow this article, although it does say that Azure plans to have SVG's gzip automatically in the future, and this was written quite some time ago:

https://coryrylan.com/blog/svg-gzip-windows-azure

I've confirmed that without this article, SVG's dont compress. When I try to add to my web.config the lines suggested in the above article, I can a generic error that the application can't load, so it's causing a pretty fundamental problem. I believe this could potentially have something to do with it conflicting with the Angular rewrite rules I need for routing of an Angular application.

This is my web.config with the modifications suggested in the previous article:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticcontent>
         <mimemap fileextension=".svg" mimetype="image/svg+xml"/>
    </staticcontent>
    <httpcompression>
         <statictypes>
           <remove mimetype="*/*"/>
           <add mimetype="image/svg+xml" enabled="true"/>
           <add mimetype="*/*" enabled="false"/>
         </statictypes>
    </httpcompression>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Has anyone had any luck compressing SVG's on an Azure Web App? SVG's are a large portion of our website and I'd really like to be able to reduce the file sizes involved there.

Comment: I don't get a start up error, but svg's refuse to compress. .Net Core's response compression middleware works, however.

Comment: Current Azure web apps seem to already include the svg config settings seen above, which you can confirm by launching Kudu, then clicking `Debug console` > `CMD` > Globe icon ("Site root") > `Config` folder > Edit (pencil) against `applicationHost.config`.

You will additionally find an empty default <urlCompression> element within this file, for which the docs show that static compression should be enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/urlcompression.

That said, while other content types compress fine, I don't see compressed svgs either.

Comment: Note that you won't see compression for static svg files < 2.7kB in size unless you override the default `httpCompression` `minFileSizeForComp` value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpCompression/  I expect the IIS team set this default because below 2700 compression overheads probably outweigh any size improvement.  https://www.itworld.com/article/2693941/why-it-doesn-t-make-sense-to-gzip-all-content-from-your-web-server.html